# C++ header file only project - use from different assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, compiler-errors

I have a project that I've had to change from having .cpp/header files separated to joining the definitions into just the header files. I tried copying the contents of the cpp file into the header file initially but my ide - VS2012 express - sent me into a loop whereby it said an header file is including itself, so when I removed the include "class.h" it complained that in the case of Class::functionname, the Class could not be recognised. Eventually I resolved to defining the definition in the headers themselves eg

```
class Thing {
public:
   void func { code; } 
}
```

This fixed my compile issues on the project. Trouble is I have a test project - WinUnit - and I can no longer access the functions. The project used to be a static library and was linked accordingly but because there are no .cpp files the project did not produce a .lib. Tried changing to dynamic link library, same issue - no dll produced. So I added a project reference and it seemed to work in that it recognised my class file when I typed #include "Class.h".

My problem is it still does not compile the classes. It does not recognise the class names at all in the test project's .cpp files. I even tried adding the header files to the test project and still no joy. I tried setting the Additional Include Directory to point to where the headers are - no good.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:
Still stuck so I created an SSCCE, it worked fine, pointed the test project at the header files directory in Additonal INclude Directories and it worked. Although the main project compiles fine, I noticed it has an intellisense error - identifier "ClassName" is undefined. All other classes recognise other classes. The #include "className" is present. When I build the test project the first error relates to this line with the intellisense error: Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

The actual line is: ClassName * obj; - it's a private variable.

There are 629 errors in the test project - some other codes: c4430, c2061. I guess these are simply side effects of the initial problem related to the class not being recognised...am lost, could back out and rethink failing this....

EDIT: fixed the intellisense errors so all errors are in the Testproject now - gone up to 826 errors. Sees the header files when including them but does not recognise any class names. error codes: c2061, c2065, c2923 etc

Comment: Why do you want to move from a well constructed project to a header only project?

Comment: In order to use an SDK, but now I found an alternate solution so have rolled back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code `func` is private, as that is the default access inside a class. Maybe you want to define the function public to be accessible for your test code and other clients of the class.

If you just put the function definitions inside the headers, you also will have to make them inline. Either explicitly (for free functions and fully specialized function template definitions), or implicitly, i.e. define class methods inside the class definition.

You are right in that the library no longer produces any compiled output, i.e. you have to link neither a lib nor a dll file. So in any project that uses the library, including your test project, you no longer have to specify the library to be linked with that project. After all, that's one of the reasons for header-only libraries: they get included completely at compile time (as opposed to link time).

If your test project compiled before, it should compile after the modification as well, provided you had all library classes under test before and did not make any changes to the namespace structures.

Without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and the proper errors you get from your compiler, one can only guess what other pitfalls you might have gotten into.

**Edit:** One thing that comes to mind that can cause trouble even if the source-to-header refactoring has been done correctly are circular includes. If you have those, you'll have to either break dependencies or put both classes into the same header, providing method definitions after both class definitions (remember to declare the method definitions inline explicitly)

**Edit2:** Simple example for a circular inclusion: classes A and B, both have a method that calls a method of the other class. So the definition of each classes method needs the *declaration* of the other class' methods, i.e. a forward declaration of the other class is not sufficient. In a normal situation the sources would include both headers and be done. In the header-only situation it will look like this for the compiler:

```
class A {
  B* b_;
public:
  A(B* b) : b_(b) {}
  void foo() {b_->meow();}
};

class B {
public:
  void bar() { A a(this); a.foo(); }
  void meow() { /* ... */}
};
```

The compiler will complain about the usage of B and the call to `B::meow()`. The former can be worked around by forward declaring B, the latter can not. Defining B first won't help, you'd have the same problem with A and `A::foo()`. So the solution has to look like this:

```
class A {
  B* b_;
public:
  A(B* b) : b_(b) {}
  void foo();   //1
};

class B {
public:
  void bar() { A a(this); a.foo(); }
  void meow() { /* ... */}
};

inline void A::foo() {b_->meow();} //2
```

The definition of the first class' methods that depend on the second class mus be delayed until after the second class' definition. Since A needs B and B needs A, there is little sense in a header-only lib to separate such intermingled class definitions in two different headers.

A way to separate such things is breaking of dependencies. In the above case that might look like this:

```
class B_Interface
{
public: 
  virtual void meow() = 0;
};

class A {
  B_Interface* b_;
public:
  A(B_Interface* b) : b_(b) {}
  void foo() {b_->meow();} //OK this time
};

class B : public B_Interface {
public:
  void bar() { A a(this); a.foo(); }
  virtual void meow() { /* ... */}
};
```

This comes at the cost of one more indirection, but separates the two classes' dependencies, enables easier testing of A etc.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the sample code, I forgot to say they were defined under the "public: " modifier. I tried explicitly making the class public as well ie public class. I will attempt an SSCCE failing a solution from any suggestions asap.

Comment: `public class` is Java or C# or something else, not C++. I'll edit the modifier into your sample code. Still, nobody except you has a clue what your code actually looks like, and so *nobody* has an idea what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks Arne, I took out the "public class" thing but the "public:" modifier is correct

Comment: In response to the edit: assuming circular dependencies exist. I think you mean - headerA includes headerB, but headerB includes headerC and headerC includes headerA - or some such scenario??? I do have include guards FWIW. But say this is a problem, do you mean copy the individual class definitions into the same header file? All my functions are now implicitly inline BTW. One thing i don't understand -do I need to reference the other assembly or give the test project access to the headers in some way - I am unclear from what you have said. They exist in the same solution?

Comment: I made another edit to show what I mean with circular dependencies/includes. Include guards won't help on those. WRT the other question in your comment: there is no other "assembly" (it's not called assembly in C++, but I'll stick to the term to avoid confusion). Since the headers get included into the test project's code, the function definitions get compiled into the test project's object code ("assembly"), and there's no separation. Since you say you get compile time errors I suppose your preprocessor already has access to the headers, so there's nothing more to do in that direction.

Comment: From your usage of "public class" and "assembly" I assume you come from C# and are not used to C++. Maybe you should make yourself clear of the differences between managed code (C#) and native code (C++), as they have completely different models of compilation, linking and execution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had enough, for some reason it still won't work and it's become a waste of my time and energy. I'm back to a well constructed project, to hell with headers only.